# как записать данные в файл на следующую строку?

Tags: c++, строки, visual-c++, fstream

у меня есть char

```cpp
char alamboba[] =
            "U2FsdGVkX1 + vzr7k2C2oMdkMR / Pajyw + 5c2qIRXt623GQ24XVVcwV + hKALd7ZMZR"
            "HPfcNNNEX7VGxaDxcraun1LOpEw0r9mA13b4ubgvX4 / Nxymw8Uj89zU3tvQ0M1oS"
            "XCIcrT3Nuyi + QHRdT77Fs4IH9K8ufbAV2idEItFzlK / JQvTQbTWHEL5Y3y1Cwu8U"
            "Xmebnzi5y6rj6m80rTPEhLTDEyDC92M + lvwPq15spN4jiAhfegdbW + XonsG5u0k2"
            "LDUd / BQ6Cp06nzUAu1wiYGgFA2KKv7kgFHjl + Buvf4X6zSfFFa9NYGNZ0JGLi1mX"
            "MuYRH + H9yAKzL29XBK + D3W8Z6OVCJNz + NV6p4YT3X50vvQS / nuaifNDKb7fSOq25"
            "rvRKodZSiLjiHzDpmaiFh7niAdSGYcZ / DRYj3GMNIWJvCSaFDbb7hczASIEGag9Z"
            "EodHxPBJBJGLUovuPIz1Hk2MVuiGi7hZKVgTgu4LeMIHM / dsc / xg8nPJzIrvl0Z +"
            "6v4IoFQGPzSvH8ebOAKRNg ==";
```

и я записываю его в файл,НО данные записываются в одну строчку.
как сделать так,чтобы они записывались НЕ в одну строчку,а так как в переменной

Comment: в переменной одна строчка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не хотите сделать

```
char alamboba[] =
        "U2FsdGVkX1 + vzr7k2C2oMdkMR / Pajyw + 5c2qIRXt623GQ24XVVcwV + hKALd7ZMZR\n"
        "HPfcNNNEX7VGxaDxcraun1LOpEw0r9mA13b4ubgvX4 / Nxymw8Uj89zU3tvQ0M1oS\n"
        "XCIcrT3Nuyi + QHRdT77Fs4IH9K8ufbAV2idEItFzlK / JQvTQbTWHEL5Y3y1Cwu8U\n"
...
```

? Или

```
char alamboba[] =
R"(U2FsdGVkX1 + vzr7k2C2oMdkMR / Pajyw + 5c2qIRXt623GQ24XVVcwV + hKALd7ZMZR
"HPfcNNNEX7VGxaDxcraun1LOpEw0r9mA13b4ubgvX4 / Nxymw8Uj89zU3tvQ0M1oS
"XCIcrT3Nuyi + QHRdT77Fs4IH9K8ufbAV2idEItFzlK / JQvTQbTWHEL5Y3y1Cwu8U
... )";
```

Comment: Работает,спасибо. Что-то сразу не догадался:D